# Проверка на наличие элемента в методе next

Tags: java

Для чего в методе `next` итератора делать проверку `hasNext`, если в цикле `for` автоматически сначала идёт проверка?

Во всех реализациях, что я смотрел она есть

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35626/iterator-implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444586/java-listiterator-implementation-specifics

Comment: причем тут for и методы итератора? непонятна суть вопроса. Можете как-то более подробно описать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в цикле `for (int element : collection)` сначала вызывается `iterator` и на каждом шаге вызывается `hasNext` + `next`. Так для чего делать проверку в `next`?

Comment: надо указывать источники где вы такое читаете......в реализации своих итераторов можно хоть кошку создать и вернуть и проверить, а в стандартной реализации этого нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно ссылку на стандартную реализацию? просто я абстрактные методы переопределяю

Comment: стандартная реализация for (.. in .. ) имеет абстрактные методы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский видимо вы не так поняли мой вопрос

Comment: а как можно понять ваш вопрос? Из того, что написано вообще мало чего можно понять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> в цикле `for (int element : collection)` сначала вызывается `iterator` и на каждом шаге вызывается `hasNext` + `next`. Так для чего делать проверку в `next`?

Как Вы правильно заметили, в Java цикл `for` в стиле `for each`:

```
for (E value : arrayList) {
    ...
}
```

[разворачивается](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) в цикл `for` с использованием итератора:

```
for (Iterator<E> it = arrayList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    E value = it.next();
    ...
}
```

Рассмотрим [стандартную реализацию](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr.next%28%29) метода `next()` класса `Iterator` в классе `ArrayList`:

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```

В явном виде метод `hasNext()` здесь не вызывается, но осуществляется проверка:

```
if (i >= size)
```

Зачем же осуществляется эта проверка, если в цикле `for each` до вызова метода `next()` мы уже проверили наличие элемента, вызвав метод `hasNext()`?

В качестве ответа на это вопрос у меня есть два предположения:

1. Банальное: а если мы используем итератор не путем записи цикла `for` в стиле `for each`, а без него и при этом не проверяем наличие элемента (проверять, разумеется, необходимо, но чисто в теории может же у кого-нибудь получится такой **ошибочный** код):

   ```
   int i = 0;
   ....
   Iterator<Integer> it = arrayList.iterator()
   while (i < N) {
       int value = it.next();
       ...
   }
   ```

   (*здесь предполагается, что* `arrayList.size() < N`). Вот в этом случае и оправдана проверка на наличие элемента в методе `next()`.
2. Небанальное: хоть в методе `next()` и проверяется, была ли модифицирована коллекция или нет, но ведь она может быть модифицирована после вызова `checkForComodification();`, но до `if (i >= size)`. В этом случае, вообще говоря, непонятно какой элемент отдавать и вообще нужно ли его отдавать (*в этом пункте могу быть не совсем прав*).

Comment: итератор же используется в основном в range циклах

Comment: я имею в виду то, что проверка идёт 2 раза: сначала при вызове `hasNext` непосредственно, а потом в методе `next` второй раз

Comment: @user229269, А с чего Вы взяли, что при вызове `next` выполняется проверка?

Comment: ну вот во всех реализация, что я смотрел она есть, сам не понимаю, для чего её делать
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444586/java-listiterator-implementation-specifics
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35626/iterator-implementation

Comment: `Метода next() проверки на наличие элемента не осуществляет, и, если следующего элемента нет, то будет сгенерировано исключение NoSuchElementException.`
так как он узнаёт, что нужно выкидывать исключение? проверкой

Comment: @user229269 эти проверки не обязательны на самом деле и это дело программиста что там в этих методах писать. Там можно просто `return array[index++];` написать и всё.

Comment: @user229269, Вроде понял Ваш вопрос – поправил ответ.

Comment: @post_zeew а `return array[index++];` разве самостоятельно не выкинет исключения?

Comment: @user229269, Выкинет, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @post_zeew раз так, то в чём смысл проверки в next тогда? более понятное название исключения?

Comment: @user229269, Вот теперь я потерял нить разговора.